# If $\sin y+\cos y=\frac{1}{2}$ then find $\frac{\sin^3y}{\cos^2y}+\frac{\cos^3y}{\sin^2y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $$\sin y+\cos y=\frac{1}{2} \tag{1}$$ Then find $$x=\frac{\sin^3y}{\cos^2y}+\frac{\cos^3y}{\sin^2y} \tag{2}$$

Given that $$\sin y=\frac{1}{2}-\cos y$$

Squaring both sides we get

$$8\cos^2y-4\cos y-3=0$$

Hence

$$\cos y=\frac{1-\sqrt{7}}{4}$$ and so $$\sin y=\frac{1+\sqrt{7}}{4}$$

substituting the above values in Eq $(2)$ and using the Binomial Theorem we get

$$x=\frac{\sin^5y+\cos^5y}{\sin^2y \cos^2y}$$ so

$$x=\frac{\dfrac{\left(1-\sqrt{7}\right)^5+\left(1+\sqrt{7}\right)^5}{4^5}}{\dfrac{36}{256}}$$

Now by the Binomial theorem $$\left(1-\sqrt{7}\right)^5+\left(1+\sqrt{7}\right)^5=2\left(1+10 \times 7+5 \times 49\right)=632$$

So $$x=\frac{\dfrac{632}{4^5}}{\dfrac{36}{256}}=\frac{79}{18}$$

I feel this is a very lengthy approach; can I get a better approach?

Comment: I think that the key point, in all the successful answers, is that the thing you want to evaluate is a rational function that's *symmetric* in the sine and cosine, $s$ and $c$. The key idea is that *a symmetric polynomial in $s$ and $c$ can be written as a sum of powers of $s+c$*; when you combine this with the ability to replace  $k(s^2 + c^2)$ with just $k$ (i.e., to reduce degrees by two), you end up with a polynomial that's at most linear in $s+c$; you can then replace $s+c$ with $\frac{1}{2}$ throughout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can i get any better approach

How about the following way?

Let $s=\sin y,c=\cos y$.

Squaring the both sides of $s+c=1/2$ gives
$$s^2+2sc+c^2=\frac 14\quad\Rightarrow\quad sc=-\frac 38.$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}\frac{s^3}{c^2}+\frac{c^3}{s^2}&=\frac{s^5+c^5}{(sc)^2}\\\\&=\frac{(s^2+c^2)(s^3+c^3)-s^2c^2(s+c)}{(sc)^2}\\\\&=\frac{s^3+c^3-(sc)^2/2}{(sc)^2}\\\\&=\frac{(s+c)(s^2-sc+c^2)-(sc)^2/2}{(sc)^2}\\\\&=\frac{(1/2)(1-sc)-(sc)^2/2}{(sc)^2}\\\\&=\frac{79}{18}\end{align}$$

Comment: Beat me by 20 secs!

Comment: You can also say that $\frac{s^3}{c^2}+\frac{c^3}{s^2} =\frac{s^3}{c^2}+\frac{c^3}{s^2} +s+c-\frac 12= \frac{s^3+cs^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^3+sc^2}{s^2} -\frac 12 = \frac{s}{c^2}+\frac{c}{s^2}-\frac 12= \frac{s^3+c^3}{s^2c^2}-\frac 12=\frac{(s +c)^3-3sc(s+c)}{s^2c^2}-\frac 12$. Same method, lower powers.

Answer (score 0):

Write 
$$
x = s (s^2/c^2) + c (c^2/s^2) 
$$
then replace $c^2 = 1-s^2$ and vice versa to get
$$
x = s (1-c^2)/c^2 + c (1-s^2)/s^2 = (s/c^2) - s + (c/s^2) - c
$$
so that
$$
x + s + c = \frac{s}{c^2} + \frac{c}{s^2} = \frac{sc^2 + cs^2}{c^2s^2} = \frac{c + s}{cs}
$$ 
Since $c + s = 1/2$, this gives
$$
x + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{cs}
$$
so 
$$
2x + 1 = \frac{1}{cs}
$$

Now 
$$
(c+s) = 1/2 \\
(c+s)^2 = 1/4 \\
c^2 + 2cs + s^2 = 1/4\\
2cs + 1 = 1/4\\
2cs=  -3/4 \\
cs = -3/8
$$
so the formula above becomes
$$
2x + 1 = \frac{1}{-3/8} = -\frac{8}{3}
$$
which you can solve.